# Win2008 R2 Enterprise Hyper V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed 2008 R2 Enterprise.  I've installed 3 Hyper V servers and went to do the 4th and it could not initialize.  If I shut down one of the other 3 the 4th starts just fine.  The hotfix 362948 did not help either.  Anyone else run accross this?

Comment: That would suggest that you're out of memory. In any case, some more detail would be handy (like an error message? I'm sure you must be getting something from the UI when you try to start the server?)

Comment: "it could not initialize" - Error code please.

Comment: I think the VTC and downvotes should slow down a bit, give him a chance to come back and add. It may very well be just low memory, but could prove useful as a quick answer to someone in the future.

Comment: 3 Hyper-V *servers* or 3 Hyper-V *virtual machines*? There is *quite* a difference there...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are out of memory on the server. This part right here seems to identify the issue as memory.

> If I shut down one of the other 3 the 4th starts just fine.

We will need more details, mainly how much physical memory the host server has and what you are assigning to the VMs.

Also, that doesn't appear to be a valid hotfix number.